# GeneXus Ev3 / Install - NO SE VE NADA

Tags: genexus

Hace tiempo que no usaba la version X Ev3 de GeneXus y ahora estoy usandola y quiero correr el comando por el shell

- c:...<dirInstallacionGenexus>\genexus /install

Y no hace nada, es decir, no veo que haga el proceso, como si se ve en la misma ventana de shell, cuando lo hago con le versión de GeneXys 16 o Gx17

También probé con:

- \genexus.exe /install
- \genexus.exe /install >Salida.txt

pero nada, cualquoer sugerencia será altamente bienvenida

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Cuando en la command line pones:

`Genexus /Install`

A partir de GeneXus v15, se ejecuta el file "Genexus.com" de tu instalacion.

Ese Genexus.com está armado como una aplicación command line, que tiene la posibilidad de mandar su output a la command line para que lo veas.

En la version en la que tu estas, GeneXus que no tiene en su instalacion el GeneXus.com y por ende el /install esta ejecutando el "GeneXus.exe" y ese no tiene forma de mostrar el output.

Para lograr ver un trace, lo que podrias hacer es habilitar el log/trace de GeneXus y buscar el log en:

```
%appdata%/Artech/Genexus/
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias Nacho @chona